# Convert a quadratic bezier to a cubic one

Tags: algorithm, vector, graphics, bezier, cubic-bezier

What is the algorithm to convert a quadratic bezier (with 3 points) to a cubic one (with 4 points)?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From https://fontforge.org/docs/techref/bezier.html#converting-truetype-to-postscript:

> Any quadratic spline can be expressed as a cubic (where the cubic term is zero). The end points of the cubic will be the same as the quadratic's.

> CP<sub>0</sub> = QP<sub>0</sub>
> CP<sub>3</sub> = QP<sub>2</sub>

> The two control points for the cubic are:

> CP<sub>1</sub> = QP<sub>0</sub> + 2/3 *(QP<sub>1</sub>-QP<sub>0</sub>)
> CP<sub>2</sub> = QP<sub>2</sub> + 2/3 *(QP<sub>1</sub>-QP<sub>2</sub>)

> ...There is a slight error introduced due to rounding, but it is unlikely to be noticeable.

Comment: Flavius has proposed `CP2 = CP1 + 1/3*(QP1-QP2)` instead. But from my math, that seems to give a different result. (Take points `QP0=(0,0)`, `QP1=(1,2)`, and `QP2=(3,0)`; I get `CP2=(5/3, 4/3)` for my formula and `CP2=(0,2)` for Flavius's.) I verified my formulas by setting the cubic coefficient to 0 and solving for the rest. Flavius, where did your formula come from?

Comment: Is QP2 the handle/anchor of the quadratic or is QP1 the handle/anchor of the quadratic ? People change the order of these every where i read up about bezier's it's a pain to keep track when people don't specify.

Comment: QP1 is the control point in the middle and QP2 is the end point.

Answer (score 21):

Just giving a proof for the accepted answer.

A quadratic Bezier is expressed as:

> Q(t) = Q<sub>0</sub> (1-t)² + 2 Q<sub>1</sub> (1-t) t + Q<sub>2</sub> t²

A cubic Bezier is expressed as:

> C(t) = C<sub>0</sub> (1-t)³ + 3 C<sub>1</sub> (1-t)² t + 3 C<sub>2</sub> (1-t) t² + C<sub>3</sub> t³

For those two polynomials to be equals, all their polynomial coefficients must be equal. The polynomial coefficents are obtained by developing the expressions (example: (1-t)² = 1 - 2t + t²), then factorizing all terms in 1, t, t², and t³:

> Q(t) = Q<sub>0</sub> + (-2Q<sub>0</sub> + 2Q<sub>1</sub>) t + (Q<sub>0</sub> - 2Q<sub>1</sub> + Q<sub>2</sub>) t²
>
> C(t) = C<sub>0</sub> + (-3C<sub>0</sub> + 3C<sub>1</sub>) t + (3C<sub>0</sub> - 6C<sub>1</sub> + 3C<sub>2</sub>) t² + (-C<sub>0</sub> + 3C<sub>1</sub> -3C<sub>2</sub> + C<sub>3</sub>) t³

Therefore, we get the following 4 equations:

> C<sub>0</sub> = Q<sub>0</sub>
>
> -3C<sub>0</sub> + 3C<sub>1</sub> = -2Q<sub>0</sub> + 2Q<sub>1</sub>
>
> 3C<sub>0</sub> - 6C<sub>1</sub> + 3C<sub>2</sub> = Q<sub>0</sub> - 2Q<sub>1</sub> + Q<sub>2</sub>
>
> -C<sub>0</sub> + 3C<sub>1</sub> -3C<sub>2</sub> + C<sub>3</sub> = 0

We can solve for C<sub>1</sub> by simply substituting C<sub>0</sub> by Q<sub>0</sub> in the 2nd row, which gives:

> C<sub>1</sub> = Q<sub>0</sub> + (2/3) (Q<sub>1</sub> - Q<sub>0</sub>)

Then, we can either continue to substitute to solve for C<sub>2</sub> then C<sub>3</sub>, or more elegantly notice the symmetry in the original equations under the change of variable *t' = 1-t*, and conclude:

> C<sub>0</sub> = Q<sub>0</sub>
>
> C<sub>1</sub> = Q<sub>0</sub> + (2/3) (Q<sub>1</sub> - Q<sub>0</sub>)
>
> C<sub>2</sub> = Q<sub>2</sub> + (2/3) (Q<sub>1</sub> - Q<sub>2</sub>)
>
> C<sub>3</sub> = Q<sub>2</sub>

Answer (score 5):

For reference, I implemented `addQuadCurve` for NSBezierPath (macOS Swift 4) based on [Owen's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162732/7488171).

```
extension NSBezierPath {
    public func addQuadCurve(to qp2: CGPoint, controlPoint qp1: CGPoint) {
        let qp0 = self.currentPoint
        self.curve(to: qp2,
            controlPoint1: qp0 + (2.0/3.0)*(qp1 - qp0),
            controlPoint2: qp2 + (2.0/3.0)*(qp1 - qp2))
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    // Vector math
    public static func +(left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
    }
    public static func -(left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: left.x - right.x, y: left.y - right.y)
    }
    public static func *(left: CGFloat, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: left * right.x, y: left * right.y)
    }
}
```