# Drawing ellipses with quadratic bezier curves and cubic bezier curves

Tags: javascript, html, bezier

I am building a JavaScript module to add convenience functions to the HTML5 canvas element.  I am trying to give as many different implementations as possible to fill out my module.  To see my progress, please visit my [project page](https://github.com/beatgammit/libcanvas) and my [examples page](http://beatgammit.github.com/libcanvas/).

I have an ellipse drawing method that uses cubic bezier curves.  I know that quadratic bezier curves can be converted to cubic bezier curves, but I have some questions:

- Is there any difference in margin for error when approximating a circle? An ellipse?
- Is there any reason to have both implementations? (performance, accuracy, etc)
- Am I missing any other methods for drawing ellipses?

P.S. This isn't directly related, but are there any other functions that would be nice to have in such a module?

Note: This is **not** a homework assignment.

EDIT: Here is my code for an ellipse (xDis is radius in x, yDis is radius in y):

```
function ellipse(x, y, xDis, yDis) {
    var kappa = 0.5522848, // 4 * ((√(2) - 1) / 3)
        ox = xDis * kappa,  // control point offset horizontal
        oy = yDis * kappa,  // control point offset vertical
        xe = x + xDis,      // x-end
        ye = y + yDis;      // y-end

    this.moveTo(x - xDis, y);
    this.bezierCurveTo(x - xDis, y - oy, x - ox, y - yDis, x, y - yDis);
    this.bezierCurveTo(x + ox, y - yDis, xe, y - oy, xe, y);
    this.bezierCurveTo(xe, y + oy, x + ox, ye, x, ye);
    this.bezierCurveTo(x - ox, ye, x - xDis, y + oy, x - xDis, y);
}
```

Related questions:

[Convert a quadratic bezier to a cubic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162645/convert-a-quadratic-bezier-to-a-cubic)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688808/drawing-quadratic-bezier-circles-with-a-given-radius-how-to-determine-control-po

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cubic Bezier curve has two more [degrees of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28physics_and_chemistry%29) than a quadratic one. It can thus reduce error further. Though the math for choosing the control-points gets more complex the higher the degree of the curve, a cubic curve should be simple enough.

The difference in performance is not much. A few more multiplications and additions.

Although this could be achieved by rotating the plane, it would be nice to be able to specify the axes of the ellipse. A center, and two axes would form the ellipse `center + cos(t)*axis1 + sin(t)*axis2`.

Another feature of the library could be different kinds of polynomial curves and splines. A [B-spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) is similar to a Bezier curve, but can continue along multiple control points.

Comment: +1 For the B-spline suggestion. I think I'm already doing what you said. I'll post my code here just in case.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a vanilla ellipse, wouldn't it be easier to plot the standard parametric form of the ellipse, and put the result through a rotation transform if it has a non-canonical orientation?

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing right now, but I'm using a cubic curve instead of a quadratic curve. Check [here](http://www.xul.fr/en/html5/canvas-curve.php). [This](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html) is the API I'm using.