# Drawing Quad Curve in OS X App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I can draw the quad curve using `UIBezierPath's` method `addQuadCurveToPoint`in iOS, but unable to find the same method in NSBezierPath.

I can see only below methods in NSBezierPath class,

```
- moveToPoint:(NSPoint)point;
- lineToPoint:(NSPoint)point;
- curveToPoint:(NSPoint)endPoint
       controlPoint1:(NSPoint)controlPoint1
       controlPoint2:(NSPoint)controlPoint2;
- closePath;
```

Is there a way to draw the quad curve in OS X environment?

Comment: You need to convert your quad curve to a cubic - there's a description here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9485788/22147

Comment: There's also `CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint` and `relativeCurve(to:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:)` functions also...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call `path.addQuadCurve(to: endPoint, controlPoint: controlPoint)`,
with code below

```
extension NSBezierPath{   
    func addQuadCurve(to endPoint: CGPoint, controlPoint: CGPoint){
        let startPoint = self.currentPoint
        let controlPoint1 = CGPoint(x: (startPoint.x + (controlPoint.x - startPoint.x) * 2.0/3.0), y: (startPoint.y + (controlPoint.y - startPoint.y) * 2.0/3.0))
        let controlPoint2 = CGPoint(x: (endPoint.x + (controlPoint.x - endPoint.x) * 2.0/3.0), y: (endPoint.y + (controlPoint.y - endPoint.y) * 2.0/3.0))
        curve(to: endPoint, controlPoint1: controlPoint1, controlPoint2: controlPoint2)
    }
}
```

Thanks to Rhythmic Fistman